# How to fopen with name already in a array of strings

Tags: c, arguments, fopen, argv, function-call

I am trying to find a way to use 
`FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode );` but passing the filename indirectly. i would also like to know how to indirectly call a function with name taken straightly from argv[].I dont want to store the string in a buffer char array. For example:

```
 int main (int argc,char *argv[])
    {
      FILE *src;
      ...
      src = fopen("argv[1]", "r");   //1st:how to insert the name of the argv[1] for example?
      ...
     function_call(argc,argv);    //2nd:and also how to call a function using directly argc argv
     ...
     }
    void create_files(char name_file1[],char name_file2[])
    {...}
```

Do i have to store length and the string of chars in order to call a function? (regarding the 2nd question) :)

Comment: Because `argv[1]` is a null-terminated string, you are not require to pass a length, `fopen()` will use `strlen()` to determine the length of the string at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `argv[1]`, it's a `char *`:

```
if (argc < 2)
    /* Error. */

src = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

Same goes for `create_files`.

```
create_files(argv[1], argv[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` takes a pointer to an array of characters. `argv` is pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of characters.

```
fopen(argv[1], "r")
```

will pass the pointer in the second position of the argv array to `fopen`.

If you want to pass `argc` and `argv` around, just pass them as they are. Their types do not change.